# JTable Look and Feel

Tags: swing, jtable

How to change the JTable's font's colors when editing by double click.
There is JTable's background color, JTable's foreground color and selection colors. How to change the colors of JTables cell editing text.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean to change the color of the cell *while* editing that cell: configure the textField used by the cellEditor:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
field.setForeground(Color.RED);
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new DefaultCellEditor(field));
```

Comment: Thankyou it works. Now how to change the border of the cell as well.