# Jtable Look and feel of editing cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, uimanager, defaulttablemodel

There is a `JTable` with `DefaultTableModel`.
There is table's `setforeground`, `setbackground` and `setselectioncolor` methods. Also when you are editing the cell you have `table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, new DefaultCellEditor(field))` method to change the editing cell's font color. 
Now how to change the border color of the editing cell.
Thankyou.`

Comment: what's wrong with textField.setBorder(...)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use any of the following keys in [`UIManager.put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#put%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to affect the corresponding `Border`:

- Table.focusCellHighlightBorder
- Table.scrollPaneBorder
- TableHeader.cellBorder

For example:

```
UIManager.put("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder",
    new BorderUIResource(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red)));
```

You can also change the color in your custom renderer/editor; [`PositiveIntegerCellEditor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7539298/230513) is an example. See also [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: +1 nice summary :-) the problem here is as simple as not being able to go the step from field.setForeground (in the previous question) to field.setBorder

Comment: Thank you! I had missed the connection to this previous, related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9224365/230513). Cross-referencing.